# unable to run apples EADemo app

Tags: iphone

I have restarted iPhone development after a long intervak and was trying to follow apple's source code 'EADemo' I guess its been configured to run on iPhone. Can you please let me know what changes needs to be done so that I can run the code on simulator.

Thanx in advannce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was better if you could upload the error. but the problem is usually the "Base SDK" version of the example.

1. you should go to the most upper app folder in the xcode file browser, right click on the icon (it should be blue with the name of the app).
2. select - "get info"
3. look for "Base SDK"
4. set it to the last updated version.
5. sometimes it is required to move between "Debug" and "Release" to get the change.
6. make sure you are on simulator.

good luck